# DFP VMAP midroll ads using Roku Ad Framework (RAF)

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am running the midroll ad urls in RAF sample code that I got from Roku website. I tested the url in google IMA video suite ispector and it has a preroll, a midroll and a postroll ad. The code works for preroll url that does not have any midroll ads (single VAST tag). But none of the ads from a VAMP url are playing in following code. When i do print 'adPods.count()' I always get result as 0.
Works for : single, inline, linear ad - http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=

Does not work for VMAP Pre-, Mid-, and Post-rolls, Single Ads : http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=

Here is the code:

```
Sub PlayContentWithAds(videoContent as Object)
    canvas = CreateObject("roImageCanvas")
    canvas.SetLayer(1, {color: "#000000"})
    canvas.SetLayer(2, {text: "Loading..."})
    canvas.Show()

    adIface = Roku_Ads()
    print "Roku_Ads library version: " + adIface.getLibVersion()
    ' Normally, would set publisher's ad URL here.  Otherwise uses default Roku ad server (with single preroll placeholder ad)
    adIface.setAdUrl("http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpost&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=")
    adPods = adIface.getAds()
    print "printing adpods count here.."
    print adPods.count()
    playContent = adIface.showAds(adPods) ' show preroll ad pod (if any)


    curPos = 0
    if playContent
        videoScreen = PlayVideoContent(videoContent)
    end if

    while playContent 
        videoMsg = wait(0, videoScreen.GetMessagePort())
        if type(videoMsg) = "roVideoScreenEvent" 
            if videoMsg.isStreamStarted()
                canvas.ClearLayer(2)
            end if
            if videoMsg.isPlaybackPosition()
                ' cache current playback position for resume after midroll ads
                curPos = videoMsg.GetIndex()
            end if
            'check for midroll/postroll ad pods
            adPods = adIface.getAds(videoMsg)
            if adPods <> invalid and adPods.Count() > 0
                ' stop video playback to prepare for midroll ad render
                videoScreen.Close()
                playContent = adIface.showAds(adPods)
                if playContent
                    ' resume video playback after midroll ads
                    videoContent.PlayStart = curPos
                    videoScreen = PlayVideoContent(videoContent)
                end if
                ' if !playContent, User exited ad view, returning to content selection
            end if ' adPods <> invalid

            if videoMsg.isFullResult() or videoMsg.isRequestFailed() or videoMsg.isPartialResult() or videoMsg.isScreenClosed()
                playContent = false
            end if
        end if ' roVideoScreenEvent
    end while
    if type(videoScreen) = "roVideoScreen" then videoScreen.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating firmware on your box. Software update will update RAF as well. Older versions of RAF might not be able to parse this XML correctly.

Comment: Thanks :) It started working with RAF 1.4. Till last week I think I was on RAF 1.4.

Comment: Hi can you please join to this chat room - chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125654/roku

Answer (score 1):

Link for posterity - it seems this is being answered at http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=89457

Comment: This got solved thru interaction on the forums and after updating my roku lib version to 1.4